# PJSIP v2.5.5 Android using PJSUA instead of PJSUA2

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I would like to know if it's possible to compile PJSIP 2.5.5 with PJSUA instead of PJSUA2? 
I want to do this because our app is based on PJSIP 2.4.0 which didn't have PJSUA2. This means that implementing PJSIP 2.5.5 would force us to rewrite most parts of the app.

**EDIT:**

Asked the wrong question, misunderstood the concept of PJSUA and PJSUA2. The question should be:

Is it possible to generate the JAVA classes based on PJSUA in PJSIP 2.5.5 instead of generating the JAVA classes based on PJSUA2 which are generated right now when building PJSIP 2.5.5?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

PJSUA and PJSUA2 are two separate API interfaces to the lower level libraries (PJSIP, PJMEDIA and PJNATH). The former is written in C and the latter is written in C++. Both are available in version 2.4.* and 2.5.*. If your application uses PJSUA, you can still use it after upgrading to 2.5.5 without modifications (at least I didn't see any incompatibilities after a quick look at the release notes).

Comment: Hi Georg,
Thanks for the reply! But how does one build only for PJSUA? Because PJSIP automatically generates PJSUA2 java classes instead of PJSUA java classes. Is there some kind of setting I need to change for this?

Comment: Well, I never used it under Java, but I believe that the Java interface has always been based on PJSUA2. Are you really sure you were using the PJSUA interface in version 2.4.5?

Comment: Hi Georg, I kinda asked the question wrong. I misunderstood the concept op PJSIP, PJSUA and PJSUA2. What I wanted to ask if we can generate the java classes based on the PJSUA API interface instead of the PJSUA2 API interface. I'll update my question so it's more clear.